# Using gcovr to show zero coverage

Tags: code-coverage, gcovr

we try to use gcovr to generate coverage report for our c++ project in Jenkins.
I was able to get it worked, but I'm stuck with one problem. gcovr doesn't show any statistics for files with zero coverage -  they have only .gcno files, no .gcda files are produced and  gcovr don't show it in results.

So I have 80% coverage for the whole project, but only 2 tests were written and it's actually 80% coverage only for source files involved in tests. 
For large project it makes of course no sense to use such statistic.

I have found https://software.sandia.gov/trac/fast/changeset/2766 this changeset as solution for this ticket https://software.sandia.gov/trac/fast/ticket/3887, but it seems not to be working.

Did I miss something?

p.s. I use gcovr 3.1-prerelease

Comment: Try updating your installation of gcovr.  The gcovr 3.1 release has been tested with uncovered files.  (See https://github.com/gcovr/gcovr).  Add a ticket on GitHub if you're still having problems.

Comment: What version of gcc are you using? According to https://github.com/gcovr/gcovr/issues/33, gcovr doesn't work with gcov's new behavoir of not generating gcda files for uncovered files.